# Django Module base not found

Tags: python, django

I'm developing with Mac OS X Lion with python 2.6 and Django from the trunk. 
I created an app named base, when I launch runserver this message appears :

```
Error: No module named base
```

I checked my sys.path, it is good. So I deleted the app, and when i'm doing a runserver or syncdb i still have the same error.

Maybe there is already a python module named "base", but i deleted my base app and the error still here.

If someone has any idea...
Thanks

Comment: Did you write some code, or just create the app and then test-run it?

Comment: My app base contain somes templates and my urls.py

Comment: Then the code which is generating this error would help.

Comment: the only output i get is this line above...

Comment: How did you create your project? By using django-admin.py startproject [project_name]? or by hand?

Comment: when you deleted the app, did you delete the entry in INSTALLED_APPS on settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

> I checked my sys.path, it is good. So I deleted the app, and when i'm doing a runserver or syncdb > i still have the same error.

You need to remove all .pyc files.

> Error: No module named base

Did you add base app to your settings.py?